# XML reading script using PHP incompletely reads some elements

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML data source URL from where I am reading the data using fread. It contains student information from which I am extracting the Grades and compiling them in an array.

The problem is when I run this script locally, it works fine and all the grades are correctly listed/collected in array. However, when I run this script on a shared server, I get some incorrectly read grades in addition the normal grade names, for example, "ergarten". The complete grade name "Kindergarten" is also recorded in the array which means that there a problem in reading only specific elements.

The first suspect I have in mind is fread byte length. I have changed it to 8192 but without luck.

Here is the relevant code chunk from the php file:

```
if (!($xml_parser = xml_parser_create())) die("Couldn't create parser.");
xml_set_element_handler( $xml_parser, "startElementHandler", "endElementHandler");
xml_set_character_data_handler( $xml_parser, "characterDataHandler");

while( $data = fread($fp, 8192)){ 
if(!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp))) {
break;}}
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: SAX is the most difficult way to read an XML - it is the most basic API. Try DOM or if the XML file is really large XMLReader. With DOM you get Xpath, and can use expression to fetch nodes from the XML tree.

Comment: Thanks ThW, but can you help me find the reason of different behavior of the script on local and remote servers? It works locally, so I would like to have it work remotely as well. It is a different matter that for making it more efficient I will definitely consider XMLReader or DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and fixed it myself.

The problem was that in the loop where the data was being read in chunks using fread, I was simultaneously converting that data using the XML parser and that was causing the problem since the streams of data do not always have a full tags. I removed the parser from that point to run it only when all the data has been read by the script.

That solved the problem.